# $a,b \in X$ and $a<b$, then there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ and neighbourhod of $V$ of $b$ such that $x<y$ whenever $x\in U$ and $y \in V$

Tags: general-topology

Let ($X,\le$)  be a linear order set, and let $\tau$ denote the order topology on $X$. Prove that for $a,b \in X$ and $a<b$, then there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ and neighbourhod of $V$ of $b$ such that $x<y$ whenever $x\in U$ and $y \in V$

$U=\{x\in X:x\leq a \}$ and $V=\{x\in X:x\ge b\}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Your $U$ and $V$ are not necessarily neighbourhoods of $a$ and $b$. Consider the case where $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual order; then $U=(-\infty,a]$ is not a neighbourhood of $a$. You may want to consider cases, depending on whether or not there is a point between $a$ and $b$ .

Comment: One way to check for errors is to ask whether your result is valid in a particular case that you are familiar with. For example, what if $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual order, with $a=0$ and $b=1$?

Comment: @bof I understood the case where $a<c<b$

Comment: what if there exists no element between a and b?

Comment: If there is no element between $a$ and $b$ then your $U$ and $b$ are fine: $$U=\{x\in X:x\le a\}=\{x\in X:x\lt b\}$$ $$V=\{x\in X:x\ge b\}=\{x\in X:x\gt a\}$$ as in Miles Zhou's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bof's comment has solved the problem. In the case where there is a point *c* between *a* and *b*, let $U=\{x\in X: x<c\}$ and $V=\{x\in X: x>c\}$. *U* and *V* satisfy the requirement; otherwise, $U=\{x\in X: x<b\}$ and $V=\{x\in X: x>a\}$ will do the trick.

Comment: Note that in the last case, if $x \in U$ and $y \in V$, we cannot have that $x \ge y$ because then $y \le x < b$ and $y >a$ would make $y$ a point between $a$ and $b$, which cannot be. So as the order is linear, $x < y$ must hold.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, which details the "trick".